# Java FileFilter

Tags: java, import, jfilechooser, filefilter

```
public class DocFilter extends FileFilter {
    public boolean accept(File f) {
        if (f.isDirectory()) {
            return true;
        }

        String extension = Utils.getExtension(f);
        if (extension != null) {
            if (extension.equals(Utils.doc) ||
                extension.equals(Utils.docx) )
            {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    //The description of this filter
    public String getDescription() { return "Just Document Files"; }
}
```

Netbeans compiler warned with the error, "No interface expected here" for above code

Anyone has idea what was the problem?? I tried changing the 'extends' to 'implements', however, it didn't seem to work that way.

and when I changed to implements, the following code cannot work,

```
chooser.addChoosableFileFilter(new DocFilter());
```

and with this error,

"method addChoosableFileFilter in class javax.swing.JFileChooser cannot be applied to given types required: javax.swing.filechooser.FileFilter"

Can anyone help on this? Thanks..

Comment: How do your imports look? Do you import the correct `FileFilter`?

Comment: yeah Joachim Sauer,

I imported the wrong library. haaha..My bad..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

medoapl brings me the answer.

JFileChooser expects a `javax.swing.filechooser.FileFilter` when your imports must state you use a `java.io.FileChooser`. The first is a class, and the second an interface. So, replace the second by the first in your import.

Comment: Most likely. Cleaning up the imports could eliminate the problem!

Comment: OMG~! I overlooked that part since Netbeans suggested the io library as the first choice and I accepted it. I suspected that already...

Thanks a lot Riduidel..^^